# SevenZFile - Apache Commons Compress 1.15, Uncompress

Tags: java, extract, 7zip, compression

While Uncompressing .7z file, Empty folders are ignored, I want to consider Empty folders as well after uncompressing any .7z file.

My Code is as below

```
SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(filename));
SevenZArchiveEntry entry;

while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null){
    if (entry.isDirectory()){
        continue;
    }

    File curfile = new File(DestinationPath,entry.getName());
    File parent = curfile.getParentFile();

    if (!parent.exists()) {
        parent.mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(curfile);
    byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
    sevenZFile.read(content, 0, content.length);
    out.write(content);
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working.

Probably the folder aren't in the "yourfile.7zip" from the beginning.

This is a common issue of 7zip and you have to update your 7zip version.

If the 7Zip contains proper arguments just use:

```
 if (entry.isDirectory()){
                 new File(DestinationPath,entry.getName()).mkdir(); 
                continue;
            }
```

Since:

> A file output stream is an output stream for writing data to a File or
>   to a FileDescriptor.

That is the proper method to accomplish the task because there's no folder implementation by native library vendor.

Comment: 7z File has some Empty Folders in it, unfortunately, the program ignores empty folders.

Comment: Mmm...ok give me a moment to rearrange the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, BlackJack, Code works but it is creating Empty Folders up to level 2, it is not going further.